# Create A loop to loop through each year and load an array for that year

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So below I have manually sorted and loaded my **water_supply1** array with data for each year, which ranges from 2015 to 2018 **AS COMMENTED** , and the way I did it I'm kinder repeating my self so I need a solution to load this data for each year in something like a for loop.

```
let water_supply1 = []
let sortedData = ["BUF", "CCT", "EKH", "ETK","JHB", "MAN", "NMB", "TSH"]

            //data for year : 2015
            water_supply1[0] = res.data.table[1].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply1[1] = res.data.table[5].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply1[2] = res.data.table[9].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply1[3] = res.data.table[13].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply1[4] = res.data.table[17].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply1[5] = res.data.table[21].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply1[6] = res.data.table[25].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply1[7] = res.data.table[29].slice(2,3)[0]
            //data for year : 2016
            water_supply2[0] = res.data.table[2].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply2[1] = res.data.table[6].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply2[2] = res.data.table[10].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply2[3] = res.data.table[14].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply2[4] = res.data.table[18].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply2[5] = res.data.table[22].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply2[6] = res.data.table[26].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply2[7] = res.data.table[30].slice(2,3)[0]
            //data for year : 2017
            water_supply3[0] = res.data.table[3].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply3[1] = res.data.table[7].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply3[2] = res.data.table[11].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply3[3] = res.data.table[15].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply3[4] = res.data.table[19].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply3[5] = res.data.table[23].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply3[6] = res.data.table[27].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply3[7] = res.data.table[31].slice(2,3)[0]
            //data for year : 2018
            water_supply4[0] = res.data.table[4].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply4[1] = res.data.table[8].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply4[2] = res.data.table[12].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply4[3] = res.data.table[16].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply4[4] = res.data.table[20].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply4[5] = res.data.table[24].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply4[6] = res.data.table[28].slice(2,3)[0]
            water_supply4[7] = res.data.table[32].slice(2,3)[0]
```

So this is how I tried doing it , but the problem with this solution it only takes the first year which is 2015 and I want to loop through and load data for all the years.

```
            let num = 0
            let no = 1

            for (let i = 0; i < sortedData.length; i++) {
              no = no + num
              array[i] = res.data.table[no].slice(2, 3)[0]
              num = 4
  
            }
            console.log('check for loop',array)
```

**result** : [87.7932138127171, 96.0160356511943, 97.238574836612, 95.0888864347421, 97.0599409338406, 98.063090378178, 92.2282248644469, 86.421762925966]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a 2D array, where the first dimension has the year and the second one your data? For example:

```
yearMapper = {
   2015: 1,
   2016: 2,
   2017: 3,
   2018: 4
}

let waterSupplyCollection = [];

for (let year = 2015; year < 2020; year++){
    let waterSupply = [];
    for (let i = 0; i<8; i++){
        let index = i*4+yearMapper[year];
        waterSupply.push(res.data.table[index].slice(2,3)[0]);
    }
    waterSupplyCollection.push(waterSupply);
}
```

In this case, there is a really simple pattern to compute the index depending on the different years, such that you don't need to assign everything manually.